# Intervals on a server

Tags: angularjs, server, client

I have recently bought a lifx lamp (a light you can control with http request to change the color) and I would like to make a website as a remote to make a cycle color.

For example, I am on the website, I click on the button cycle 1, each seconds, with a $interval() (setInterval()), Angular send a HTTP request to the lamp and that work.

However, I'd like to know how can a make this job (send a request each seconds) on the server with a back-end language.

I wonder if angular send a request to a PHP page with the intervals will work.

Otherwise, (I'm a newbie in AngularJS) is there a way to to this job with angular but in server side.

If I really want to do that in server side, it's because I would like that the cycle continues even if I shut down the computer (client side)

Ask if you need more information

Thank you and sorry for my aweful English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to write a server-side script for this, you don't need Angular. Consider using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Something like this should work:

```
var request = require('request');
var interval = 1000; // 1 second, in milliseconds
function changeColor() {
  /* some code to pick a random color */
  request('http://url-for-lifx-api.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
       setTimeout(changeColor, interval);
    } else {
      /* handle error */
    }
  });
}
changeColor();
```

**NOTE:** You will need to modify the request to use the proper HTTP method (GET, PUT, POST) and, if necessary, pass headers or a body with the request.

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, I've never used NodeJS. (I just use Angular without yo) so that will be perfect to start nodejs

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Please accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to it, or let me know if it does not fully answer your question so I can revise it.